How to get exact exit code that a snakemake job exited with?
When a snakemake job errors with a non-zero exit code, snakemake prints:
(one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message

How can I find out what the exact exit code is? I want to know the error code, i.e. 1, 138 etc. with which the job exited.
I'm surprised snakemake doesn't report the exit code explicitly, because explicit is better than implicit.

In the documentation, presently here, an example of exiting with a certain non-zero status code is provided, which I have included below. You can probably use similar logic to print out the exit code instead.
shell:
    """
    set +e
    somecommand ...
    exitcode=$?
    if [ $exitcode -eq 1 ]
    then
        exit 1
    else
        exit 0
    fi
    """

For instance, you could output $? to get the exit code.

Thanks, I figured out something like this - but it's ridiculous snakemake doesn't just say on its own what the exit code is. Why hide the information? It's literally 3 characters at most ;)
I think I"ll make an issue.

@CorneliusRoemer did you end up making an issue? At my job we are trying to make a production workflow in Snakemake for which we need this behaviour of catching exit codes. To justify any workaround ( we are thinking to just run the command using puthon subprocess from the shell) some documentation that this isn't natively possible in Snakemake would be helpful.

@HarryMatthews I don't think I made one in the end. Would be great if you could do so!
